# Django: csrf_exempt doesn't work

Tags: django, csrf

`Django`: 1.9.7 / `Python` 3.5.1

**views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse

class OrderPayCheckView(View):

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse(
            data={
                "valid": False,
            }
        )
```

When I send `POST` request to this url via `POSTMAN`, it shows,
`403 Forbidden` - `CSRF authentication Fail` kinda thing (I really want to show all errors, but the language is Korean)

I tested it in my test server which has its own url.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 9):

Put decorator before view then will work properly.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse

@csrf_exempt
class OrderPayCheckView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse(
            data={
                "valid": False,
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thanks. what if I don't use View in django but only url ?

Comment: @Dejell for example, `('^my_page/$', csrf_exempt(direct_to_template), {'template': 'my_page.html'})`